# Return majority weighted vote from array based in columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix `x` with `3 x 3` dimensions and a vector `w` that is `3,`:

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
              [3, 2 ,1],
              [1, 2, 2]])

w = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.3])
```

I need to generate another vector `y` that is a majority vote for each row of  `x`. Each column of `x` is weighted by the corresponding value in `w`. Something like this:

for `y[0]`, it should look for `X[0] => [1, 2, 1]`

- columns with value 1 = first and third [0,2]
- columns with value 2 = second [1]
- columns with value 3 = none

Sum the weights (in `w`) of the columns grouped by its value in X:

- sum of weights of columns with value 1: `0.3 + 0.3 = 0.6`
- sum of weights of columns with value 2: `0.4`
- sum of weights of columns with value 3: `0`

Since the sum of weights of columns with value 1 is the highest, `y[0] = 1`. And so on.

Comment: Just as an FYI, there is a bug in the accepted answer (comment and solution below). I've posted an alternative that may work for you as well.

Comment: the bug has not been accepted yet ;-) but at least from the discussion I included the extra case when there is no winner, which I suppose you will want your code to handle.

Comment: @joann255, perhaps it would be a good idea to have the expected result for more than one row, and include the test case mentioned below (x=[[2, 2, 4, 1]], w=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with numpy if you understand [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The downside is that because the code is vectorized, you do more computations than you need. This would matter if the size of the `w` vector is very large.

Perhaps someone comes up with an easier way to write it, but this is how I would do it without thinking too much.

**The answer first:**

```
i = np.arange(3) + 1
m = (x.reshape((1,4,3)) == i.reshape((3,1,1)))
np.argmax(np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w, axis=1) + 1
```

**Now the step-by-step explanation...** Note that it is usually better to start counting from zero, but I followed your convention.

1. I added one row so the array is not symmetric (easier to check shapes)

   ```
    In [1]: x = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
       ...:               [3, 2 ,1],
       ...:               [1, 2, 2],
       ...:               [3, 1, 3]])
       ...:
       ...: w = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.3])
   ```
2. The first step is to have the array of indices `i`. Your convention starts at one.

   ```
    In [2]: i = np.arange(3) + 1
   ```
3. **the tricky step**: create an array with shape (3,4,3), where the i-th entry of the array is a (4,3) array with all entries 0 or 1. It is 1 if and only if x == i. This is done by adding dimensions to `x` and `i` so they can be broadcasted. The operation basically compares all combinations of `x` and `i`, because all dimensions of `x` match size=1 dimension of `i` and viceversa:

   ```
    In [3]: m = (x.reshape((1,4,3)) == i.reshape((3,1,1)))*1

    In [4]: m
    Out[4]:
    array([[[1, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1]]])
   ```
4. now you sum along rows (which is axis=2) to get the number of times each selection appeared in each row of `x` (note that the result is transposed when you compare it to `x`):

   ```
    In [5]: np.sum(m, axis=2)
    Out[5]:
    array([[2, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 2, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 2]])
   ```
5. I hope you can already see where this is going. You can read directly: In the first row of `x`, `1` appears twice and `2` appears once. In the second row of `x`, all appear once, in the third row of `x`, `1` appears once, `2` appears twice, etc.
6. multiply this by the weights:

   ```
    In [7]: np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w
    Out[7]: 
    array([[0.6, 0.4, 0. ],
           [0.3, 0.4, 0.3],
           [0.3, 0.8, 0. ],
           [0.3, 0. , 0.6]])
   ```
7. get the maximum along the rows (adding one to conform to your convention):

   ```
    In [8]: np.argmax(np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w, axis=1) + 1
    Out[8]: array([1, 2, 2, 3])
   ```

**Special Case: a Tie**

The following case was brought up in the comments:

```
x = np.array([[2, 2, 4, 1]])
w = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
```

the sum of the weights is:

```
[0.1, 0.4, 0., 0.4]
```

so in this case there is no winner. It isn't clear from the question what one would do in this case. One could take all, take none... One can look for these cases at the end:

```
final_w = np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w
result = np.argmax(np.sum(m*w, axis=2), axis=0) + 1
special_cases = np.argwhere(np.sum(final_w == np.max(final_w), axis=1) > 1)
```

**Note:** I used the reshape method for readability, but I often use [np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) or np.newaxis. Something like this:

```
i = np.arange(3) + 1
m = (x[np.newaxis] == i[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
np.argmax(np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w, axis=1) + 1
```

**an alternative:** you could also use some kind of compiled code. For example, numba is pretty easy to use in this case.

Comment: I think that your solution works by coincidence. You should consider changing `np.argmax(np.sum(m, axis=2).T*w, axis=1) + 1` to `np.argmax(np.sum(m*w, axis=2), axis=0) + 1`. Here is a test case: `w = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`, `x = [[[2, 2, 4, 1]]`. I adjusted your indices appropriately to handle a 1x4 case

Comment: I think you might be confused by the + 1 so indices start at 1. Your test case is interesting because it is a tie, and the calculation does not complain about it.

In your test case, the final weights are [0.1, 0.4, 0. , 0.4], so the result should be `2` and `4`. My code gives only `2`. Your suggestion gives `1`. One would have to make a check for this.

Comment: OP is not multiplying the weights by `x`. `x` is just a label. The final weights are [0.3, 0.3, 0.4], which is not a tie.

Comment: I am not considering cases where there is a tie since they have a very little probability of occurring. In my real scenario, weights are floats with at least 5 decimal numbers. I just gave you weights with 1 decimal case for simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really crazy way to do it, which involves sorting and indexing rather than adding a new dimension. This is sort of like the sort-based method used by `np.unique`.

First find the sorted indices in each row:

```
rows = np.repeat(np.arange(x.shape[0]), x.shape[1])  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
cols = np.argsort(x, axis=1).ravel()                 # [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
```

Now you can create an array of sorted elements per-column, both unweighted and weighted. The former will be used to get the indices for summing, the latter will actually be summed.

```
u = x[rows, cols]                            # [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]
v = np.broadcast_to(w, x.shape)[rows, cols]  # [0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3]
```

You can find the breakpoints to apply `np.add.reduce` at:

```
row_breaks = np.diff(rows).astype(bool)            # [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
col_breaks = np.diff(u).astype(bool)               # [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
break_mask = row_breaks | col_breaks               # [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
breaks = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(break_mask) + 1]  # [ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10]
```

Now you have the sums of the weights for identical numbers in each row:

```
sums = np.add.reduceat(v, breaks)  # [0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6]
```

But you need to break them up into segments corresponding to the number of unique elements per row:

```
unique_counts = np.add.reduceat(break_mask, np.arange(0, x.size, x.shape[1]))
unique_counts[-1] += 1  # The last segment will be missing from the mask: # [2, 3, 2, 2]

unique_rows = np.repeat(np.arange(x.shape[0]), unique_counts)  # [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

You can now sort each segment to find the maximum value:

```
indices = np.lexsort(np.stack((sums, unique_rows), axis=0))  # [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The index at the end of each run is given by:

```
max_inds = np.cumsum(unique_counts) - 1  # [1, 4, 6, 8]
```

So the maximum sums are:

```
sums[indices[max_inds]]  # [0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6]
```

And you can unravel the indices-within indices to get the correct element from each row. Notice that `max_inds`, and everything that depends on it is the same size as `x.shape[1]`, as expected:

```
result = u[breaks[indices[max_ind]]]
```

This method does not look very pretty, but it is likely more space efficient than using an extra dimension on the array. Additionally, it works regardless of the numbers in `x`. Notice that I never subtracted anything or adjusted `x` in any way. In fact, all the rows are treated independently, and the coincidence of a maximum element being identical to the minimum of the next is broken by `row_breaks` when constructing `breaks`.

**TL;DR**

Enjoy:

```
def weighted_vote(x, w):
    rows = np.repeat(np.arange(x.shape[0]), x.shape[1])
    cols = np.argsort(x, axis=1).ravel()
    u = x[rows, cols]
    v = np.broadcast_to(w, x.shape)[rows, cols]
    row_breaks = np.diff(rows).astype(bool)
    col_breaks = np.diff(u).astype(bool)
    break_mask = row_breaks | col_breaks
    breaks = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(break_mask) + 1]
    sums = np.add.reduceat(v, breaks)
    unique_counts = np.add.reduceat(break_mask, np.arange(0, x.size, x.shape[1]))
    unique_counts[-1] += 1
    unique_rows = np.repeat(np.arange(x.shape[0]), unique_counts)
    indices = np.lexsort(np.stack((sums, unique_rows), axis=0))
    max_inds = np.cumsum(unique_counts) - 1
    return u[breaks[indices[max_inds]]]
```

**Benchmarks**

Benchmarks are run in following format:

```
rows = ...
cols = ...
x = np.random.randint(cols, size=(rows, cols)) + 1
w = np.random.rand(cols)
%timeit weighted_vote_MP(x, w)
%timeit weighted_vote_JG(x, w)
assert (weighted_vote_MP(x, w) == weighted_vote_JG(x, w)).all()
```

I used the following generalization for `weighted_vote_JG`, with appropriate corrections:

```
def weighted_vote_JG(x, w):
    i = np.arange(w.size) + 1
    m = (x[None, ...] == i.reshape(-1, 1, 1))
    return np.argmax(np.sum(m * w, axis=2), axis=0) + 1
```

*Rows: 100, Cols: 10*

```
  MP: 440 µs ± 5.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
* JG: 153 µs ± 796 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

*Rows: 1000, Cols: 10*

```
  MP: 2.53 ms ± 43.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
* JG: 1.03 ms ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

*Rows: 10000, Cols: 10*

```
  MP: 23.5 ms ± 200 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
* JG: 16.6 ms ± 67.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Rows: 100000, Cols: 10*

```
  MP: 322 ms ± 3.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
* JG: 188 ms ± 858 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*Rows: 100, Cols: 100*

```
* MP: 3.31 ms ± 257 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  JG: 12.6 ms ± 244 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Rows: 1000, Cols: 100*

```
* MP: 31 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  JG: 134 ms ± 581 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*Rows: 10000, Cols: 100*

```
* MP: 417 ms ± 7.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  JG: 1.42 s ± 126 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Rows: 100000, Cols: 100*

```
* MP: 4.94 s ± 25.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  JG: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.45 GiB for an array with shape (100, 100000, 100) and data type float64
```

Moral of the story: for small number of columns and weights, the expanded solution is faster. For a larger number of columns, use my version instead.

Comment: Nice to see the benchmarks, to see the point where the number of columns becomes large. I still do not see why weighted_vote([[2, 2, 4, 1]], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]) == [1]. In this case, `1` appears once (0.1), 2 appears twice (2*0.2), `3` never appears, 4 appears once (0.4). So the final weights are [0.1, 0.4, 0., 0.4]. The maxima are 2 and 4.

Comment: @Javier. Look at OP's example: "sum of weights of columns with value 2: 0.4". Notice that it's not 0.8. OP is using `x` as labels only, not as part of the sum.

Comment: @Javier. The word in the title should perhaps be "conditioning" rather than "weight"

Comment: In the OP: in the first row, the value `2` appears once. This corresponds to i==1, and w[1] == 0.4. I do not know where one would get the 0.8. What I did in my previous comment was to follow the same procedure as in the OP, but with your test case, so there is no confusion with indices. Following that procedure, `2` and `4` tie on first with a total weight of 0.4. Your method gives `1` as result.

Comment: perhaps the OP needs to be expanded with a longer worked example, perhaps add the expected result for a few rows, to make sure we are understanding it right. In other words: I understood that the result from your test case should be a tie between 2 and 4.

Comment: @Javier. Looking at OP's example, you are saying the second row should select 3, right? Because 0.3*3 > 0.4*2>0.3*1. But OP chooses 2, because the weights are not multiplied by the x-values. He wants the label whose weights sum to the greatest value. `x` can contain characters for all anyone cares.

Comment: No. I am not saying that, and that is not what my code gives as result either. This discussion is already too long, and I would prefer if @joan just gives the answer to your test case so we can decide what is going on. We could move it to a chat, but if we do not agree, it is better make the OP explicit.